# is this the most efficient way?

Tags: java, arrays, big-o

I'm looking for the greatest difference between 2 doubles in a list, I have done it this way in NlogN time, is there a way to do it in linear time? thanks!

```
public static double NlogN(double[] ar){
    Arrays.sort(ar);
    double max=ar[ar.length-1];
    double min=ar[0];
    double difference=max-min;
    return difference;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about not sorting the array first, but just traversing it, collecting the minimum and maximum value?

```
public static double linear(double[] ar) {
    double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    double min = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

    for(double elem: ar){
        if(min > elem) {min = elem;}
        if(max < elem) {max = elem;}
    }

    return Math.abs(max-min); 
}
```

Comment: What if there is a `negative double value` ?

Comment: ah i initialized the max value false. `Double.MIN_VALUE` is not the smalest negative number as i thought. it is the smalest positive number. I edited my solution accordingly. With  `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`  and `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` it is working with postivie and negative doubles

Comment: Can I please ask you why you set max to NEGATIVE_INFINITY, i thought max should represent the positive infinity? same goes for in the loop, shouldn't it be max> elem? instead of min>elem

Comment: every time when a value which is bigger than `max` is found, `max` is set to the new value. So for the initialization of `max`, i choose to get the smales possible value. Then the next value found will be bigger than that and `max` will be set acordlingly. If `max` would be set to `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` then no value can be bigger than that and the max value will always be `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`. But you want it to be the biggest value of your array.

Comment: Would it make sense if I do this? double min = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
     double max = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

     for(double x: ar){
         if(max > x) {max =x;}
         if(min < x) {min =x;}
     }

     return Math.abs(max-min);

Comment: ok thank u so much, but I have tried, its giving me the same output

Comment: for(double x: ar){ if(max > x) {max =x;} since when going through the list, max is taking the largest value it can find that is >x.

Comment: try both versions with this array `double[] ar = {-1.0,-2.0,7.0,-0.5};` and you will see a difference

Comment: and the output is? are you testing the wrong method? When i do it your way, i get `INFINITY` as output. When i do it as described above i get `9.0` as result

Comment: Yes, I tested both code, gives the same output 9. Did you make it absolute value? return Math.abs(max-min);

Comment: Please kindly check if you are interested, i have posted the code below as an answer

Comment: i see now, that you have switched the `<` and `>` in the if statements as well, then of course its the same. But then your variable `max` will hold the smales value of your array. Try printing out `max` and `min` then you will see...

Comment: Oh yes! spot on, I'm wrong after all :) thank u so much! that was good learning

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to sort the whole array. You can iterate on it only once and find the smallest and biggest number. I think a simple for would be faster. The complexity will be N since you iterate the array once.

```
            double smallest = ar[0];
            double largetst = ar[0];

            for(int i=1; i< ar.length; i++)
            {
                    if(ar[i] > largetst)
                            largetst = ar[i];
                    else if (ar[i] < smallest)
                            smallest = ar[i];

            }

           result = largest-smallest;
```